# primary key exception while saving changes when multiple objects added

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a list of objects in the type of some entity object 
I am using ms sql server 2008

I wrote a code that goes something like this :

```
foreach (some_entity_obj obj_to_handle in this.some_entity_obj_list)
{
  try
  {
    db.some_entity_obj.AddObject(obj_to_handle);

    if (dbsaveCounter % 10 == 0)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();

        this.monitor.SyncValues(some_monitoring_unit, another_monitoring_unit);
        some_monitoring_unit = 0;
        another_monitoring_unit = 0;

    }
    if (obj_to_handle.some_monitoring_unit != null)
        some_monitoring_unit += (double)obj_to_handle.some_monitoring_unit;
    if (obj_to_handle.another_monitoring_unit != null)
        another_monitoring_unit += (double)obj_to_handle.another_monitoring_unit;

    dbsaveCounter++;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    this.monitor.PushToUnsecceeded_rows(obj_to_handle,ex);
    this.monitor.PushToErrors("Error in ** : ", ex, false);
  }
}
db.SaveChanges();
this.monitor.SyncValues(some_monitoring_unit, another_monitoring_unit);
```

I get the following exception :
Unable to determine the principal end of the 'the entity object' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

if i save the changes every run of the loop it works

Here is a shorter version of my question :

Why does this works :

```
foreach (foo _entObj in someList)
{
   db.foo.AddObject(_entObj);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

and this does not work :

```
 int cnt = 0;
    foreach (foo _entObj in someList)
    {
       db.foo.AddObject(_entObj);
       if (cnt%10 == 0)
          db.SaveChanges();
       cnt++;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The error is likely caused by a foreign key ID (as opposed to a reference) which cannot be resolved. Have assigned proper values to any properties (columns) of your 'some_entity_obj' that uses a foreign key in the SQL database?

Comment: all the values are correct.. if dont save the changes every 10 loops (cancel that if statement) it works fine. there is only a primary key that (identity auto increment)

Comment: edit in your entire model (relevant parts to reproduce), it likely is related.